# Mongodb, WiredTiger error when I create an index

Tags: database, mongodb, csv

I am inserting through MongoDBCompass some .csv files (each large one) in a specific collection! the files consist of an date,log and event! all entered as a string:

```
date;log;event
01-02-2021;ok;xx234-qwerty
01-02-2021;no;122;xx333-asdffg
02-02-2021;ok;121-xx444-ertyu
.......
.......
etc etc
```

unfortunately creating the index of the entire collection composed of the various .csv files all cleaned up through Python, pandas and jupyter I have the following error:

```
"c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"WiredTiger error"
```

to create the index I run from the command prompt:

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({event: "text"})
```

it would seem that in the various .csv files that I upload from compass there is something that creates problems! but I don't know what!
it is a procedure that I have always used and it has never created problems for me, maybe there are too many files? (I have about 30.000000 lines).
I only need the event as an index, is there any character in the event column that creates the error when creating the index? how could i solve the problem in your opinion?
Thanks

Comment: can you try **db.mycollection.createIndex( { event: 1 })**